# Group the most frequent items in a column associated with the most frequent items in another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Having the following data frame, I'd like to find the 2 most frequent groups in the 'first' column, and within each group find the 2 most frequent groups in the 'second' column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'first': list('cbbcbcbccabc'), 'second': list('zvvzwyzyxxwz')})
df
```

gets

```
  first second
0   c   z
1   b   v
2   b   v
3   c   z
4   b   w
5   c   y
6   b   z
7   c   y
8   c   x
9   a   x
10  b   w
11  c   z
```

and by `df.groupby(['first']).size()` we get

```
first
a    1
b    5
c    6
```

so, 'c' and 'b' are the most frequent items in the 'first' column. We want the 2 most frequent items in the 'second' column within 'c' and 'b' groups. If we do `df.groupby(['first', 'second']).size()` we get

```
first  second
a      x         1
b      v         2
       w         2
       z         1
c      x         1
       y         2
       z         3
```

therefore we're interested in 'z' and 'y' within 'c', and 'v' and 'w' within 'b', that is

```
first  second
c      z         3
       y         2
b      v         2
       w         2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think here is possible use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), because sorting by default by counts - first is filtered top2 values, filtered DataFrame and the is returned top2 per groups with change order by `idx` values:

*Notice - Filtering by `m` is not necessary, but added for better performance (processing only 2 groups instead all)*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first': list('cbbcbcbccabc'), 'second': list('zvvzwyzyxxwz')})

idx = df['first'].value_counts().head(2).index
m = df['first'].isin(idx)
df = (df[m].groupby(['first'])['second']
           .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().iloc[:2])
           .reindex(idx, level=0)
           .rename_axis(['first','second']))
print (df)
first  second
c      z         3
       y         2
b      w         2
       v         2
Name: second, dtype: int64
```

Solution for 3 levels:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'second': list('cbbcbcbccabc'),
                   'third': list('zvvzwyzyxxwz')})

#3 column df
df = (pd.concat([df, df], keys=('a','b'))
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('first')
        .reset_index())
# print (df)


idx = df['first'].value_counts().head(2).index
m = df['first'].isin(idx)
idx1 = (df[m].groupby(['first'])['second']
            .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().iloc[:2])
            .index)
print (idx1)

df = df.set_index(['first','second'])
df = (df.loc[idx1].groupby(['first','second'], sort=False)['third']
        .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().iloc[:2])
        .rename_axis(['first','second','third']))
           
print (df)
first  second  third
a      c       z        3
               y        2
       b       w        2
               v        2
b      c       z        3
               y        2
       b       w        2
               v        2
Name: third, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if we wanna expand the solution to the 'third' column?

Comment: @Morteza - It means top2 for first level, top2 for first, second and top2 for first, second, third level? Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: The same thing with the first two columns will be expanded to a third column. So, one more dimention.

Comment: @Morteza - Not so easy, added some solution.